# Finding a future co-linear midpoint of two moving objects

Tags: optimization, kinematics

I have three objects in a 2d space: S, E<sub>1</sub>, and E<sub>2</sub>.

E<sub>1</sub> and E<sub>2</sub> are at some location ((E<sub>1<sub>x</sub></sub>, E<sub>1<sub>y</sub></sub>) & (E<sub>2<sub>x</sub></sub>, E<sub>2<sub>y</sub></sub>)) and moving at constant velocities V<sub>E<sub>1</sub></sub> and V<sub>E<sub>2</sub></sub>. They will be set initially and not change.

S starts at some location and needs to pick a direction. It has a speed and can only move at this speed.

How does one select the exact direction that will result in S being both equidistant from and co-linear to E<sub>1</sub> and E<sub>2</sub> in the minimum amount of time.

Comment: Just to clarify, all these objects move in a straight line? Also, are you assuming that the initial configuration is such that this is even possible? For example, if $E_1$ starts at $(-1,1)$ and $E_2$ starts at $(1,1)$, both moving due North at speed $v_0$, and $S$ starts at $(0,0)$ and has speed $v_0$, then the three objects can never be co-linear.

Comment: Yes. Everything moves in a straight line. The project will require them to collide with walls later but I will take whatever implementation I have and make it piece-wise to deal with that. Your concern is more than valid and I need to specify that S will have a much higher speed than the other two objects. But I can't specify what "much higher" means since the project constraints aren't specified yet. I would be fine with a solution (or point in the direction of a solution) that finds a solution if one exists and simply breaks if one doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume $S$ starts at the origin. If $S$ has constant speed $s$ and chooses a constant heading $\vec h_S$ where $|\vec h_S|=1$ then its position at time $t$ is

$\vec S(t) = (st) \vec h_S$

Let's call the midpoint of $E_1$ and $E_2$ $F$, so at time $t$

$\vec F(t) = \frac 1 2 \left( \vec E_1(t) + \vec E_2(t) \right)$

Then $F$ starts at position

$\vec F(0) = \frac 1 2 \left( \vec E_1(0) + \vec E_2(0) \right)$

and has constant velocity

$\vec v_F = \frac 1 2 \left( \vec v_{E_1} + \vec v_{E_2} \right)$

and so its position at time $t$ is

$\vec F(t) = \vec F(0) + t\vec v_F$

Then $S$ intercepts $F$ at time $t$ if

$(st) \vec h_S = \vec F(0) + t\vec v_F \\ \Rightarrow t(s \vec h_S - \vec v_F) = \vec F(0)$

So $S$ has to choose its heading $\vec h_S$ so that $s \vec h_S - \vec v_F$ is parallel to $\vec F(0)$. As pointed out in a comment, if $s$ is too small this may not be possible.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I was worried this might be a Calculus of Variations problem. But simple kinematics does the trick.